# issue with fopen on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, fopen

I'm having the issue with fopen() on google app engine. Works normal 3-4 times and than this response from server.

> Message: fopen(https://website_url/image_name.png): failed to open
>   stream: Connection closed.

Any idea how to troubleshoot what happened and why?

```
$image = "https://website_url/image_name.png";  
$f = fopen($image,'rb');
```

php ini has `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately without code there is little we can do to help.  You should consider adding some.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the correct path.
You need to give fopen the full path of the file, and you don't need chdir() at all. Try this version:

```
$path_to_file='url';
```

$fh = fopen($path_to_file.$filename, 'w') or die('Permission error');